# Intersection between polygons layers is empty

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection

I'm trying to compute the area of green surface for cities with QGis from open data found online. I have *polygons on a layer* for the **cities boundaries** and *polygons on another layer* for the **parks**.

I first decided to *clip* the polygons of the parks but as the boundaries of the cities are adjacent, the parks are not cut along the boundaries.

I then chose to *intersect* both layers as it would cut the parks alongside the boundaries. But the **result is empty**! Any clue?

I've already checked the CSR which are the same for both layers.

[image: Example of what I would like to have]

For example, in this picture, there are two parks (North one *foret communale du canton du Cerisier* and South one *foret communale*) and two cities (*376* West and *519* East). As the limits of the parks are not the same as the ones of the cities, it should return 4 green areas: two for the North forest (one for each city) and two for the South forest (one for each city).

Here are the files I'm using: https://files.fm/f/cpuyqu2f.

**Edit: Seems like the problem comes from park layer. I tried with new layers and the polygons intersection works.**

Comment: I have had this occur too when trying to perform the operation on a layer that is being edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was quite simple in fact: my parks layer is a 3D layer (*Polygon* with XYZ) and the cities layer is a 2D layer (*Polygon* with XY). The intersection was not happening for obvious reasons (the 3D layer being litteraly above the 2D layer and not intersecting it).

I **saved** my parks layer as a new layer **without checking** *include Z dimension* and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem some time ago. My solution was to use the SAGA intersection tool that comes in QGIS instead of the QGIS Geoprocessing tool and it worked out. I still don´t know why the other tool didn´t do the job.
So search in the toolbox panel for the SAGA intersection and see if that one works out.

I´m using QGIS 2.14

Comment: Thank you, using SAGA intersection did work. I think that SAGA is converting the third dimension or ignoring it. I am going to look into the code of saga (if it's available somewhere) to make sure about this.